# intermediate sha256 computation on HMAC, observing wrong hash value

Tags: python, hash, sha256, hmacsha256

I am trying to run do a step by step implementation of HMAC using sha256 based on the https://csrc.nist.gov/CSRC/media/Projects/Cryptographic-Standards-and-Guidelines/documents/examples/HMAC_SHA256.pdf.
I am observing wrong hash value in the intermediate sha256 computation as shown below.

```
text = 0x53616d706c65206d65737361676520666f72206b65796c656e3d626c6f636b6c656e
key = 0x000102030405060708090a0b0c0d0e0f101112131415161718191a1b1c1d1e1f202122232425262728292a2b2c2d2e2f303132333435363738393a3b3c3d3e3f  
ipad = 0x36363636363636363636363636363636363636363636363636363636363636363636363636363636363636363636363636363636363636363636363636363636

key_xor_ipad = key ^ ipad 

# https://csrc.nist.gov/CSRC/media/Projects/Cryptographic-Standards-and-Guidelines/documents/examples/HMAC_SHA256.pdf
# Hash((key^ipad)||text)
key_xor_ipad_or_text = key_xor_ipad | text
print hex(key_xor_ipad_or_text)
```

This is the output I get
`0x36373435323330313e3f3c3d3a3b383926272425222320212e2f2c2d2a2b7b697f777c75327f75737f7f7f7d3a7f7f7b266f657d6e676e3d6e6f6f6f6b6f6d6f`

We calculate the sha_256 hash on the above data.

```
# I am using the following link to input the above hex result (not string) to find the sha256 hash
# https://emn178.github.io/online-tools/sha256.html
```

The resulting hash I get is
`ca6e2f2f319acd6a6e9a7e63f8141e67ff2f4cbad14e2a5149d1f8ccb770ad0d`

I was expecting to get the following hash based on
https://csrc.nist.gov/CSRC/media/Projects/Cryptographic-Standards-and-Guidelines/documents/examples/HMAC_SHA256.pdf

`C0918E14C43562B910DB4B8101CF8812C3DA2783C670BFF34D88B3B88E731716`

I am not sure if I am missing something obvious.

Comment: I would interpret `||` in that formula to mean concatenation, rather than bitwise OR.

Comment: Thank you, I will make the modification and give that a try.

Comment: @jasonharper You are correct, that was indeed concatenation. After the modification, the hash actually matches.